# Using regex to remove sentence after occurrence of key phrase python

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a regex solution to remove any words in the rest of the sentence after the occurrence of a key phrase.

**Example**

sentence =  "The weather forecast for today is mostly sunny. The forecast for tomorrow will be rainy. The rest of the week..."

Key_phrase = "for tomorrow"

Desired output = "The weather forecast for today is mostly sunny. The forecast. The rest of the week..."

**Attempt**

```
head, sep, tail = sentence.partition(key_phrase)
print(head)
```

My idea is to first split the string into sentences, apply the above technique and then join the results. However, I feel like there must be a more elegant way to do this with regex?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `re.sub`

**Ex:**

```
sentence = "The weather forecast for today is mostly sunny. The forecast for tomorrow will be rainy. The rest of the week..."
key_phrase = "for tomorrow"
print(re.sub(fr"({key_phrase}.*?)(?=\.)", "", sentence))
```

Output

```
The weather forecast for today is mostly sunny. The forecast . The rest of the week...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```py
re.sub(fr"{re.escape(key_phrase)}[^.]*", "", sentence)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/EiRBsT/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  for                      'for'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \                        ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  tomorrow                 'tomorrow'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^.]*                    any character except: '.' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##XY/BCsIwEETv@Yolp1YkF8/@hTdRSeuWhLZJ2N1SgvjtsS0UxcPAHN7MMCmLi@FUih9TJAFCxRgEQ4twBn1xCDNacUjQRcLWsqwGJD5tBs8wRpYhA08hZAMr/8eNkSjOMPthgAaBrN9BwgWKHcg2gr0xRqse8yM5srzt/1ZolcgHqQgNT03VkX4tFrm1CatvrH5f7@Z20EfQi/Yzda1K@QA):

```py
import re
sentence = "The weather forecast for today is mostly sunny. The forecast for tomorrow will be rainy. The rest of the week..."
key_phrase = "for tomorrow"
print(re.sub(fr"{re.escape(key_phrase)}[^.]*", "", sentence))
```

**Results**: `The weather forecast for today is mostly sunny. The forecast . The rest of the week...`